# How did Shanks manage to stop Kaido?

Tags: one-piece

I know it sounds funny, but how on earth Shanks stopped Kaido to enter and follow Whitebeard on Marineford war?

Comment: It's unknown in the manga and anime still, but Shanks should have equal strength as a Yonko to escape and follow Whitebeard

Comment: @AnimatedLime I'm sure that once WCI closes and the rest of the crew goes to Wano they are gonna elaborate. Then elude to a showdown between Luffy and Shanks post-wano arc. But that's considering that Luffy faces Shanks before Blackbeard. Just my .02

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All we really know about Shanks and Kaido's skirmish is in these 2 Panels.

[image]
[image]

*Anything said other than the information is merely speculation. However it is not completely unfounded.*

Looking at the second panel, Shanks appears at Marineford just a day after his skirmish, with his crew and ship showing no signs of damage or a fight. Considering, what happened to Marineford when Yonko Whitebeard fought we can safely assume that whatever fight, if it took place was likely very minor. More plausible is, **Shanks simply being there "stopped" Kaido**. Consider the following scenario.

The fight between Whitebeard and World Government threatened to disrupt the balance between the Yonko. Kaido tried to use this opportunately to preemptively strike at his enemy while he is distracted. Neither Whitebeard nor WG can afford war on two fronts. Whitebeard couldn't waste time and resources to thwart Kaido while WG didn't engage Rayleigh (Kizaru said something like do you want to fight 2 legends iirc)

Thus Shanks being a fellow Yonko just simply appeared there and stopped Kaido. Kaido doesn't want to fight other Yonko's head on either. The balance exists because they are all evenly matched. Thus the scuffle between Shanks and Kaido was likely very minor. Seeing that Kaido will not allow him to attack Whitebeard, Kaido retreated while Shanks followed Whitebeard to Marineford.

An interesting parallel to real world, Is Indo-Pak war in 1971. [From WIkipedia: Task Force 74](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Force_74)

> The US Task Force 74 was a US Navy task force of the United States Seventh Fleet that was deployed to the Bay of Bengal by Nixon administration in December 1971, at the height of the 1971 Indo-Pakistani War. Led by the Aircraft carrier USS Enterprise, the deployment of the task force was seen as a show of force by USA in support of the beleaguered West Pakistani forces. [..] 
>   To counter this, On 6 and 13 December 1971, the Soviet Navy dispatched two groups of cruisers and destroyers and a submarine armed with nuclear missiles from Vladivostok; they trailed US Task Force 74 into the Indian Ocean from 18 December 1971 until 7 January 1972. The Soviets also had a nuclear submarine to help ward off the threat posed by USS Enterprise task force in the Indian Ocean

Thus without fighting, both US and USSR effectively negated each other's influence on the war. For a more detailed account: [1971 War: How Russia sank Nixon’s gunboat diplomacy](http://in.rbth.com/articles/2011/12/20/1971_war_how_russia_sank_nixons_gunboat_diplomacy_14041)

Comment: Your hypothesis is good and plausible, but do you have any source to back up your claim? If not, please specify that you are making assumptions.

Comment: @solalito I thought the language implied it clearly that I am trying to logically deduce the nature of fight between the 2 yonkos. AnimatedLine's comment on the question makes it quite clear that we have no concrete information on it. Anyways, edited the answer to make it more explicit and added the relevant Manga panels.

Answer (score 0):

this is my own opinion based on my own search and theories :

shanks is based on chancai a.k.a red boy from the novel "journey to the west".the name itself shanks reflect a combination between chancai and "truks" from dragon ball  z.
in the same novel a character known as "demon lord" heavily influenced the making of kaido's character along side with the Mongolian emperor kaidu, and he is chancai's father.

so how did shanks stop kaido? he probably cut a deal with his old man :)

Comment: Are you saying Shanks is Kaido's son?

Comment: @Arcane he is implying that he is either literally his son or he is metaphorically his son (a mentor).  Sounds like a good theory but it is clearly a fan theory.  I would love to see his evidence though.

Comment: yes i'm saying shanks is the biological son of kaido, wanna hear me? :D

Comment: i don't know if i'm allowed to post outside links in here otherwise i'm happy to link a full detailed theory on the matter backed up by reference ,u let me know if it's "legal" :)

Comment: well..I disagree with the comment. If kaido is shanks father then wont he stop luffy from going against Kaido?

Comment: i'll recommend reading the novel journey to the west not only did it happens it also forshadow luffy(wukng) vs shanks(red boy) in which he got owned badly here's my theory on the matter backed up by references picked up from wikipedia that talks about this https://orojackson.com/threads/ultimate-swordsmen-theory-part-ii-volume-2.16587/